# How can i filter out the duplicate entries on my data set with the sum of zero

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, duplicates

Highlighted below is a duplicate data which has different trip_total_amount. I want them to get out of my query results since their sum is equals to zero.

This is my query to get this data:

```
SELECT * FROM efleet_copy AS e1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT mta_id, COUNT(mta_id) FROM efleet_copy WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 02
  AND mta_id LIKE '_________'
 GROUP BY mta_id HAVING COUNT(mta_id) > 1) AS e2
ON e1.mta_id = e2.mta_id
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 02
ORDER BY e1.mta_id ASC, ride_id ASC, trip_number ASC;
```

[image: data set]

Comment: When your query uses multiple tables, it's a good practice to prepend the table alias to each column. For example, instead of `ride_id` it's better to use `e1.ride_id`. Otherwise it becomes confusing for the readers like us.

Comment: Showing just the results of the current query might not be enough to get a proper answer. It would be good if you could add sample data and expected output to your question, so we could try and optimize it as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
with cte0 as 
(
    SELECT * FROM efleet_copy AS e1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT mta_id, COUNT(mta_id) FROM efleet_copy WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 02
      AND mta_id LIKE '_________'
     GROUP BY mta_id HAVING COUNT(mta_id) > 1) AS e2
    ON e1.mta_id = e2.mta_id
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 02
    ORDER BY e1.mta_id ASC, ride_id ASC, trip_number ASC
)
SELECT * from cte0 c
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM CTE0 ci
    WHERE c.ride_id = ci.ride_id 
    GROUP BY ride_id 
    having sum(trip_total_amount) = 0 
)
```

Comment: Amazing. Your query works, i just need to add ::money on the zero value to work. This is a great help, thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck